# ring over a with macron?

Tags: characters

I am trying to put a ring over an a with a macron, but i cannot position the ring properly. it shows up too far to the left and not in the center. this is the best that i have been able to do:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps},SlantedFont={Latin Modern Roman Slanted}]{Latin Modern Roman}
    \newcommand{\myring}{\char"030A}
    \newcommand{\ringlonga}{%
      \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
        \ialign{##\cr
                \hidewidth\char"030A\hidewidth\cr
                \noalign{\kern-1ex}
                \char"0101\cr}
      }%
    }

\begin{document}
\ringlonga
\end{document}
```

how do i shift the ring to the right?

Comment: it would help if you gave a complete test document and said what tex system and what fonts you are using. given the size of the numbers you are passing to tex I assume that you are not using classic tex, but even xetex and luatex default to cmr10 which has no characters above 127

Comment: it was compiled in lualatex.

Comment: Combining characters in Latin Modern are often misplaced. `:(` The placement is correct with CMU Serif.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

[image]

although the added kern is tuned to this character it may work reasonably in other contexts.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps},SlantedFont={Latin Modern Roman Slanted}]{Latin Modern Roman}
    \newcommand{\myring}{\char"030A}
    \newcommand{\ringlonga}{%
      \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
        \ialign{##\cr
                \hidewidth\kern.45em\null\char"030A\hidewidth\cr
                \noalign{\kern-1ex}
                \char"0101\cr}
      }%
    }

\begin{document}
\ringlonga
\end{document}
```

Probably more correct to use the non-combining ring here and as it doesn't require adjustment may work more generally:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps},SlantedFont={Latin Modern Roman Slanted}]{Latin Modern Roman}
    \newcommand{\myring}{\char"02DA}
    \newcommand{\ringlonga}{%
      \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
        \ialign{##\cr
                \hidewidth\null\char"02DA\hidewidth\cr
                \noalign{\kern-1ex}
                \char"0101\cr}
      }%
    }

\begin{document}
\ringlonga
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Herea are two possibilities, if the vertical separation of the first attempt is not acceptable.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps},SlantedFont={Latin Modern Roman Slanted}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\def\rla{\stackengine{5.8pt}{\r a}{\rule{5pt}{.4pt}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\rla
\def\rla{\stackengine{1.4pt}{\=a}{\r{}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\rla
\end{document}
```

[image]